# Returning MVC partial view to jQuery memory leak

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui-dialog

I'm writing an application in MVC to output a table View. One of the columns in the table contains an action link that loads up a jQuery UI dialog. When I save the data from the dialog  I call a GridRefresh controller method that grabs the newly stored data and returns a partial view back through ajax to repaint the grid with the new partial view html. I use the $('#mainGrid').html(data) jQuery call to overwrite the html on the page. This call does as it should and correctly replaces the contents of the Div, but I end up with a 4mb leak every-time the RefreshGrid function is called. I've tried numerous fixes from articles online including: using .empty(), .remove(), .replaceWith(), clearing jQuery.fragments, clearing the div element using javascript(getElementById). Nothing seems to work.

**Note:** The data size of the response with the html view is around 1.2MB, could the size be causing my troubles? I am using MVC3 with jQuery 1.10.2 and IE9

**MVC Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public PartialViewResult RefreshGrid(DateTime effectiveDate, String searchVal)
{
    if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
    {
        var gridModel = new GridModel();

        LoadGridDataFromDB(effectiveDate,searchVal);
        return PartialView("Grid", gridModel);
    }

    return null;
}
```

**Ajax/jQuery**

```
$.ajax({
  url: "Home/RefreshGrid",
  type: "post",
  data: {
         effectiveDate: effectiveDate,
         searchVal: searchVal
  },
  dataType: "html",
  success: function(data){
    alert("success");
    $("#mainGrid").html(data);
  },
  error:function(){ alert("failure");}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried accomplishing the same functionality using plain MVC - Ajax.BeginForm should do the trick. I have used it numerous times and I have never noticed any memory leaks. A simple example would be

View.cshtml

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Action_name", "Controller_name", new AjaxOptions {
                                        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                                        HttpMethod = "POST"
                                        ...})
{
   Html.Partial("PartialView_name")
}
```

Comment: Vasil, using your method how can I tell all client browsers to refresh when new data comes in?

Comment: InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace 
this is the option that tells MVC what exactly to do with the received data. In this case everything that is in the using block will be replaced by the response. Other options are InsertionMode.InsertAfter and InsertionMode.InsertBefore

Comment: I believe you provided the correct answer, my only concern is that when I click the save button on the jQuery UI dialog, how do I tell MVC to update the Grid on each machine that is running my MVC application?

Comment: If I understand you correctly you want all the people that are on that page to see the updated grid? If so you would need to change the approach and use something like web socket to maintain a persistent connection and notify the client of the change as you cannot do that in plain HTTP. However if this is not exactly what you are after and need to implement some custom logic you can take a look at the AjaxOptions class.